# Where is "limit selection to visible" button in Blender 4.0?

Tags: weight-painting

After the major Blender update to version 3.0, all options have been moved; and as of 4.0, they have been moved even more. I am trying to weight paint, and I want to paint all the way through the object so I do not miss a single spot. The "toggle X-ray" button is not the same thing and has no effect whatsoever. In Blender 2.79, the "limit selection to visible" button was at the bottom next to the selection modes (vertices, faces, edges) but it is not there anymore, nor is it at the top.

Comment: Hi. Does the method mentioned at ~1 minute into this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLWv9yjVaoU work for you?

Comment: Yes. This solved my problem. Thank you.